# How to change color of NbSuffix/NbPrefix

Tags: nebular

I'm trying to change the color of the icon when my mouse is going out of focused input. https://prnt.sc/s6atkb

```
<nb-form-field>
    <nb-icon nbPrefix icon="search-outline"></nb-icon>
    <input type="text" fieldSize="medium" nbInput>
</nb-form-field>
```

I don't find anything talking about NbSuffix/NbPrefix inside the Input Nebular Documentation.

Thanks for helping,

Answer (score 0):

You can set a class or style with color attribute like

```
<nb-icon nbPrefix icon="search-outline" style="color: red"></nb-icon>
```